# Incremental seek on MySQL result

Tags: php, database, mysql

When outputting data in a large file, I try to make it a habit to incrementally output data in chunks, to prevent reading the entire large file into memory. As an example to show what I mean:

```php
$fp = fopen('path/to/file.txt', 'r');
while (!feof($fp)) {
    echo fread($fp, 8192);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Would this same practice be possible when fetching values from a database result? If so, how? As far as I'm aware, the ability to fetch unbuffered results from MySQL only applies to a row-by-row basis - and not per column.

A basic example is shown below (I am aware that the mysql extension is deprecated - this is merely for illustrative purposes):

```php
$q = mysql_incremental('SELECT `filedata` FROM `large_files` WHERE `id` = 1');
while (!mysql_incremental_eof($q, 'filedata')) {
    echo mysql_fetch_incremental($q, 'filedata');
}
mysql_free_result($q);
```

A possible solution that I thought of is to combine multiple queries for portions of the file, making use of the `SUBSTRING()` function available in MySQL. I would imagine that although this might be more memory efficient, I'm wondering what the effect would be on network usage as well as disk activity?

Comment: Sounds like you are prematurely optimizing here.  Has this *actually* been a problem?

Comment: No, it hasn't actually been a problem. The question was more to see whether there was a way to efficiently stream data from MySQL through PHP.

Answer (score 1):

if your database contains large files that you do not want to be sent in their entirety, your database has a design flaw.  Depending on how finished your code is, said flaw may not be worth correcting... but since you're taking about saving memory, it's probably a good place to start.

Create a new recordset consisting of the chunks you want for each page from the `large_files` table.  You can try doing this as a View, or it may be necessary to create a table.

If alerting the database is not an option, write your large file to disk in a temporary location on your php server, and read it as you would any other flat file.

(by and large all of your separation of the file will increase net traffic and/or disk usage, assuming the client wants all of the file.  And if the client DOESN'T always want the entire file, that's another sign of a database design flaw.)